# Change Windows Mobile 5.0 Emulator RAM Size

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, device-emulator-manager

I can't change the memory size for a Windows Mobile 5.0 emulator. This is what I have tried.

In Visual Studio 2008 Professional, I can try to change the RAM size of an Emulator by going to Tools->Options->Device Tools->Devices. From there I select a device (I am working with USA Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC R2 Emulator) and click the Properties button -> Emulator Options button. I check the Specify RAM size box and change it to 256 and hit OK -> OK -> OK.

This does not change anything. When I launch that emulator from Visual Studio, and then from inside the emulator go to Start -> Settings -> System -> Memory, it shows the following 2 totals:

Storage: 31.42MB

Program: 36.99MB

From the emulator window if I go to File -> Configure..., it shows the RAM size still set to 128, and yet according to the emulator OS there is less than 128 anyway. I know I had this working before I switched from XP to Windows 7. I have tried clearing the saved state, before and after making the changes. I have tried doing a soft and a hard reset with the emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working. I closed all emulator instances and then from Device Emulator Manager I cleared the saved state of the emulator. I exited the Device Emulator Manager. I changed the setting from inside Visual Studio again. I launched the emulator from Visual Studio by selecting Start Debugging with my Smart Device project open, and then I selected the emulator. Not sure exactly what I did wrong before though...

Comment: The key seems closing running emulator, exit `Emulator Manager`, run `Emulator Manager` again, (1st thing) right click, execute `Clear saved state` and re-`Connect`. Sth. seems  holding the saved state and prevents it from being cleared.